# How do I select a set number of variables out of a list on Python

Tags: python, list, random

I was wondering how I'd select a set number of variables out of a list using python

For example:
If my list was - `list=["a","b","c"]`
and I wanted to select 2 of the variables I the list how would I do so?

Comment: Which two do you want? (I'm guessing by the "random" tag that you want to pick any two at random, but you should say that explicitly in your question.)

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
random.sample(set(list), 2)
```

This will select random two values from list